# frame.setResizable(false) not working! It changes window size instead of keeping dimensions

Tags: java, window, jframe, resizable, dimension

```
frame.setResizable(false);
```

in my TestCalculator class makes my JFrame for my Calculator class unresizable (not a word), but it adds a few pixels within the frame, on the bottom and right sides... or removes some from a panel or two. i dont know exactly how to word it, but **I want to make the frame a fixed size without the extra pixels and junk**.

Yes, I did ask on another site, but they could not help me, and this is due tomorrow morning and I've been working on this for about two weeks and just made the calculator work yesterday. I have been googling it all day and night, and can't find a specific solution.

I'm not sure exactly what is causing it to not act right (duh), but it could be anywhere in this code, maybe the order of it, idk.

CALCULATOR CLASS:

```
public class SimpleArithmeticCalculator extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

 private static final int BTN_ONE = 0;

 private static final int BTN_TWO = 1;

 private static final int BTN_THREE = 2;

 private static final int BTN_DIV = 3;

 private static final int BTN_FOUR = 4;

 private static final int BTN_FIVE = 5;

 private static final int BTN_SIX = 6;

 private static final int BTN_MULT = 7;

 private static final int BTN_SEVEN = 8;

 private static final int BTN_EIGHT = 9;

 private static final int BTN_NINE = 10;

 private static final int BTN_MINUS = 11;

 private static final int BTN_ZERO = 12;

 private static final int BTN_DECIMAL = 13;

 private static final int BTN_POWER = 14;

 private static final int BTN_PLUS = 15;

 private static final int BTN_CLEAR = 16;

 private static final int BTN_PERCENT = 17;

 private static final int BTN_BACKSPACE = 18;

 private static final int BTN_CALC = 19;

 private static final int NUM_BUTTONS = 20;



 private static final int OP_MULT = 0;

 private static final int OP_DIV = 1;

 private static final int OP_PLUS = 2;

 private static final int OP_MINUS = 3;

 private static final int OP_POWER = 4;

 private static final int OP_PERCENT = 5;

 private static char[] buttonTexts = {'7' , '8' , '9' , '/' , '4' ,
            '5' , '6' , '*' , '1' , '2' ,
            '3' , '-' , '0' , '.' , '^' ,
            '+' , 'C' , '%' , '<' , '='};

 private static final int[] buttonKeys = {
  KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD7 , KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD8 , KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD9 , KeyEvent.VK_DIVIDE , KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD4 ,
  KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD5 , KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD6 , KeyEvent.VK_MULTIPLY , KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD1 , KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2 ,
   KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD3 , KeyEvent.VK_MINUS , KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0 , KeyEvent.VK_STOP, '^',
   KeyEvent.VK_PLUS, KeyEvent.VK_C , '%' , KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE , KeyEvent.VK_ENTER
 };

 private Font font;

 private JButton[] buttons;

 private JTextField displayText;

 public JPanel calcPanel;

 private JPanel textPanel;

 private JPanel buttonPanel;

 private String buffer;

 private int op;

 private int opStored;

 private double lhs;

 private double rhs;

 private double rhsStored;

 private boolean left;

 private boolean clear;

 private char lastAction;

    public SimpleArithmeticCalculator() {

      super();

  buffer = new String("0.0");

  op = -1;

  opStored = -1;

  lhs = 0.0;

  rhs = 0.0;

  rhsStored = 0.0;

  left = true;

  clear = true;

  lastAction = '=';

     font = Font.decode("Courier PLAIN 24");

     try {

       UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

     }

     catch (Exception e) {

     }

  calcPanel = new JPanel();

  textPanel = new JPanel();

  buttonPanel = new JPanel();

  buttonPanel.setForeground(null);

  textPanel.setForeground(null);

  calcPanel.setForeground(null);

  textPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1,0,0));

  buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5 , 10 , 10 , 10));

  displayText = new JTextField("" , 20);

  displayText.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);

  displayText.setFont(font);

  displayText.setEditable(false);

  textPanel.add(displayText);

  buttons = new JButton[NUM_BUTTONS];

  for (int i = 0 ; i < NUM_BUTTONS ; ++i) {

    buttons[i] = new JButton("" + buttonTexts[i]);

    buttons[i].setMnemonic(buttonKeys[i]);

    buttons[i].setFont(font);

    buttons[i].setMinimumSize(new Dimension(50,50));

    buttons[i].setActionCommand("" + buttonTexts[i]);

    buttons[i].addActionListener(this);

    buttonPanel.add(buttons[i]);

  }

  buttons[BTN_POWER].setText("^");

  buttons[BTN_PERCENT].setText("%");

  buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));

  textPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));

  calcPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  calcPanel.add(textPanel , BorderLayout.NORTH);

  calcPanel.add(buttonPanel , BorderLayout.CENTER);

  add(calcPanel);

     for (int i = 0 ; i < NUM_BUTTONS ; ++i) {

       buttons[i].setMaximumSize(buttons[i].getSize());

     }

     }

 public void SetColors(Color bg , Color textbg , Color textcolor) {

   calcPanel.setBackground(bg);

   calcPanel.setVisible(true);

   calcPanel.setOpaque(false);

   buttonPanel.setBackground(bg);

   buttonPanel.setVisible(true);

   buttonPanel.setOpaque(false);

   textPanel.setBackground(bg);

   textPanel.setOpaque(false);

   textPanel.setVisible(true);

   displayText.setBackground(textbg);

   displayText.setForeground(textcolor);

   for (int i = 0 ; i < NUM_BUTTONS ; ++i) {

     buttons[i].setForeground(textcolor);

   }

 }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {

  String action = ev.getActionCommand();

  char c = action.charAt(0);

  boolean calc = false;

 if (c == buttonTexts[BTN_CLEAR]) {

   buffer = "";

   left = true;

 }

 else if (c == buttonTexts[BTN_BACKSPACE]) {

   if (buffer.length() > 0) {

     buffer = buffer.substring(0 , buffer.length() - 1);

   }

   if (lastAction == buttonTexts[BTN_CALC]) {

     left = true;

   }

   clear = false;

 }

 else if ((c == buttonTexts[BTN_CALC]) || isOpCharacter(c)) {

   int opCurrent = op;

   if (c == buttonTexts[BTN_CALC]) {

    if (!left) {

      calc = true;

      if (isOpCharacter(lastAction)) {

        rhs = GetBufferValue();

        rhsStored = rhs;

        opCurrent = op;

        opStored = op;

      }

      else if (lastAction == buttonTexts[BTN_CALC]) {

      rhs = rhsStored;

      opCurrent = opStored;

      }

      else {

      rhs = GetBufferValue();

      rhsStored = rhs;

      opCurrent = op;

      opStored = op;

      }

    }

   }

   else if (isOpCharacter(c)) {

    opStored = op;

    if (c == buttonTexts[BTN_MULT])  {op = OP_MULT;}

    if (c == buttonTexts[BTN_DIV])   {op = OP_DIV;}

    if (c == buttonTexts[BTN_PLUS])  {op = OP_PLUS;}

    if (c == buttonTexts[BTN_MINUS]) {op = OP_MINUS;}

    if (c == buttonTexts[BTN_POWER])  {op = OP_POWER;}

    if (c == buttonTexts[BTN_PERCENT]) {op = OP_PERCENT;}

    if (lastAction == buttonTexts[BTN_CALC]) {

      lhs = GetBufferValue();

      clear = true;

    }

    else if (isOpCharacter(lastAction)) {

    }

    else {


      if (left) {

        lhs = GetBufferValue();

        left = false;

      }

      else {

        calc = true;

        rhs = GetBufferValue();

        opCurrent = opStored;

        opStored = op;

      }

      clear = true;

    }

   }

   if (calc) {

    double result = 0.0;

    if (opCurrent == OP_MULT)  {result = lhs * rhs;}

    if (opCurrent == OP_DIV)   {result = lhs / rhs;}

    if (opCurrent == OP_PLUS)  {result = lhs + rhs;}

    if (opCurrent == OP_MINUS) {result = lhs - rhs;}

    if (opCurrent == OP_POWER) {result = Math.pow(lhs,rhs);}  

    if (opCurrent == OP_PERCENT) {result = lhs / 100;}

    lhs = result;

    buffer = "" + result;

    clear = true;

   }

  }

 else {

   if (lastAction == buttonTexts[BTN_CALC]) {

    left = true;

   }

   if (clear) {

    buffer = "";

    clear = false;

   }

   if (c == buttonTexts[BTN_DECIMAL]) {

    if (buffer.indexOf('.') == -1) {

     if (buffer.length() == 0 || (buffer.length() == 1 && buffer.charAt(0) == '-')) {

       buffer += "0";

     }

     buffer += ".";

    }

   }

   else if (c == buttonTexts[BTN_ZERO]) {

    if (buffer.length() == 0 || (buffer.length() == 1 && buffer.charAt(0) == '-')) {

      buffer += "0.";

    }

    else if (buffer.length() > 0 && (isNonZeroNumber(buffer.charAt(0)) ||
            (buffer.charAt(0) == '-' && isNonZeroNumber(buffer.charAt(1))))) {

      buffer += "0";

    }

    else if (buffer.compareTo("0") == 0 || buffer.compareTo("-0") == 0) {

    }

    else {

      buffer += "0";

    }

   }

   else {

    if (!buffer.equals("0") && !buffer.equals("-0")) {

      buffer += c;

    }

   }

 }

  lastAction = c;

  displayText.setText(buffer);

 }

 public double GetBufferValue() {

   double d = 0.0;

   try {

     d = Double.parseDouble(buffer);

   }

   catch (NumberFormatException e) {

   System.out.println("NumberFormatException in GetBufferValue()");

   }

   return d;

 }

 public boolean isOpCharacter(char c) {

   return ((c == buttonTexts[BTN_MULT]) ||

           (c == buttonTexts[BTN_DIV]) ||

           (c == buttonTexts[BTN_PLUS]) ||

           (c == buttonTexts[BTN_MINUS]) ||

           (c == buttonTexts[BTN_POWER]) ||

           (c == buttonTexts[BTN_PERCENT]));

 }

 public boolean isNumericCharacter(char c) {

  return ((c == buttonTexts[BTN_ZERO]) ||

    (c == buttonTexts[BTN_ONE]) ||

    (c == buttonTexts[BTN_TWO]) ||

    (c == buttonTexts[BTN_THREE]) ||

    (c == buttonTexts[BTN_FOUR]) ||

    (c == buttonTexts[BTN_FIVE]) ||

    (c == buttonTexts[BTN_SIX]) ||

    (c == buttonTexts[BTN_SEVEN]) ||

    (c == buttonTexts[BTN_EIGHT]) ||

    (c == buttonTexts[BTN_NINE]) ||

    (c == buttonTexts[BTN_DECIMAL]));

 }

 public boolean isNonZeroNumber(char c) {

  return (c == buttonTexts[BTN_ONE] ||

    c == buttonTexts[BTN_TWO] ||

    c == buttonTexts[BTN_THREE] ||

    c == buttonTexts[BTN_FOUR] ||

    c == buttonTexts[BTN_FIVE] ||

    c == buttonTexts[BTN_SIX] ||

    c == buttonTexts[BTN_SEVEN] ||

    c == buttonTexts[BTN_EIGHT] ||

    c == buttonTexts[BTN_NINE]);

 }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

}

}
```

TEST CLASS:

```
public class TestCalculator {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

        ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon("01_Crane_AGweb.jpg").getImage());

        SimpleArithmeticCalculator calc = new SimpleArithmeticCalculator();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Arithmetic Calculator");

        frame.setResizable(false);   

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.getContentPane().add(calc);

        **frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(343,343));**

        frame.pack();

        frame.setVisible(true);      

        **frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(343,371));**

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel.setVisible(true);

        panel.setOpaque(true);

        panel.add(calc);

        calc.SetColors(null , Color.white , new Color(72,61,139));

        calc.setVisible(true);

        calc.setOpaque(false);

}

}

class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

  private Image img;

  public ImagePanel(String img) {

    this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());

  }

  public ImagePanel(Image img) {

    this.img = img;

    Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));

    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(size));

    this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(size));

    this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(size));

    this.setSize(new Dimension(size));

    **this.setLayout(null);**

  }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),this);

    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, stop trying to make the frame "the right size", and make the content the "right size"

Comment: @user3078712 Edited your post

Comment: It's all 358x379 I thought. @MadProgrammer

Comment: Why are you messing around with your code again? You have already been told that your code is wrong, that you can't just add two components to the CENTER of a BorderLayout. And you can't add components to the frame after you do a  pack() or setVisile() on the frame. You have also been told not to use a null layout on your background panel. Why are you wasting our time reposting question when you don't even follow the advice you have been given. No wonder it takes you several weeks to work on the code!

Comment: The frame has borders, the content area is the viewable within these borders, not all platforms have the same borders...

Comment: @camickr I'm messing around w/ it because it WORKS for the most part, thank you very much. It's just that ONE part. Your suggestions may not have helped me, but someone else's did. It's just the frame. So, I don't understand your hostility, but no thanks. It actually took me one week. That was an error. Btw, this is my first semester taking Java, so I'd appreciate it if you calmed down. Thanks.

Comment: No it doesn't work or you wouldn't be asking a question again. The code does NOT work because you have been trying to set sizes everywhere instead of using layout managers properly as you have been advised in the past. I am frustrated because you continue to ask question when you have already been given answers!! So now you are wasting the time of anybody who takes the time to read this question. They are just going to repeat the same advice.

Comment: THIS is what the WORKING calculator looks like: http://i926.photobucket.com/albums/ad110/Khamani_Moore/calc_zps3890d76f.jpg

Comment: It actually DOES work. The CALCULATOR works. I asked for help w/ adjusting the PANELS on ANOTHER post YESTERDAY. THAT STUFF WORKS. SEE THE LINK. THIS is a totally DIFFERENT question, THANK YOU VERY MUCH. So, please, don't accuse me of doing something possibly pushing others away from helping me if you don't have the facts. @camickr

Comment: Your question is about the sizing of the frame. I told you the problem is because you are trying to hard code sizes everywhere (and not letting the layout managers do their jobs) and you are adding components to the panel after the frame has been packed, which will affect sizing when you play with the setResizable() method. You have been advised not to do this in previous postings.

Comment: Please, refrain from from SHOUTING, especially at one of the senior/experienced posters

Comment: Refrain from shouting when she basically is wrong and accusing me harshly?? Okay, sure. Sorry for hurting anyone's feelings like she did mine. Experience doesn't mean you can be disrespectful. I only posted three questions on this site, and none specifically about frame.setResizable(false); before this one! Lol. What are you talking about? I asked David about how to make the frame size fixed and he told me to use .setResizable(false); and I told him it did not work, and he told me he didn't know why not. Then, I said I'd google the answer, and I did. Now, I'm here.

Answer (score 4):

Frames have borders.  If done right, `pack` will attempt to create a viewable area (the space within the frame borders) to match the preferred size of the content pane.

Instead of worrying about the size of the frame, let the two components and the layout manager make determination themselves...

[image: Before]

The first value is the size of the image panel/image, the second is the size of the window.

Make sure you always call `setResizable` BEFORE calling `pack`...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Window;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon("/path/to/image").getImage());
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Arithmetic Calculator");
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

    private Image img;

    public ImagePanel(String img) {
        this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());
    }

    public ImagePanel(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
        Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
        Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
        int y = fm.getAscent();
        g.drawString(getWidth() + "x" + getHeight() + "; " + window.getWidth() + "x" + window.getHeight(), 0, y);
    }
}
```

**Update with simple layout example**

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Window;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class TestCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestCalculator();
    }

    public TestCalculator() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon("/path/to/image").getImage());
                panel.add(new Calculator());
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Arithmetic Calculator");
                frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Calculator extends JPanel {

        public Calculator() {
            setOpaque(false);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            add(new JTextField(), BorderLayout.NORTH);

            JPanel keysPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 4, 8, 8));
            keysPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 0, 0, 4));
            keysPane.setOpaque(false);
            String keys[] = new String[]{
                "7", "8", "9", "/",
                "4", "5", "6", "*",
                "1", "2", "3", "-",
                "0", ".", "^", "+",
                "C", "%", "<", "=",
            };
            for (String key : keys) {
                keysPane.add(new JButton(key));
            }
            add(keysPane);
        }

    }

    class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

        private Image img;

        public ImagePanel(String img) {
            this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());
        }

        public ImagePanel(Image img) {
            this.img = img;
            Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(size));
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(16, 16, 16, 16));
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
            int y = fm.getAscent();
            g.drawString(getWidth() + "x" + getHeight() + "; " + window.getWidth() + "x" + window.getHeight(), 0, y);
        }
    }

}
```

**Updated from extended example**

The order in which you do things is very important.  Generally speaking, you want to initialize the interface, add all the components you need, pack the frame and make it visible...

This, generally isn't what you are doing.  Instead of doing something like...

```
ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon("01_Crane_AGweb.jpg").getImage());
SimpleArithmeticCalculator calc = new SimpleArithmeticCalculator();

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Arithmetic Calculator");

frame.setResizable(false);   
// This is not going to come out well, as BorderLayout
// will only allow a single component to occupy the CenterPosition
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
frame.getContentPane().add(calc);
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(343,343));
// Now sized to the preferred size of the calc pane...
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);      
frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(343,371));
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
// Rather pointless as Swing components are visible by default...
panel.setVisible(true);
panel.setOpaque(true);
// This is now going to change the preferred size of the window...
panel.add(calc);
```

You could do something more like...

```
ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon("01_Crane_AGweb.jpg").getImage());
SimpleArithmeticCalculator calc = new SimpleArithmeticCalculator();

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Arithmetic Calculator");

panel.setVisible(true);
panel.setOpaque(true);
panel.add(calc);
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setResizable(false);   
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Instead...

**Full running example...**

[image: Calc]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestCalculator100 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestCalculator100();
    }

    public TestCalculator100() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon("01_Crane_AGweb.jpg").getImage());

                SimpleArithmeticCalculator calc = new SimpleArithmeticCalculator();
                calc.setOpaque(false);
                panel.add(calc);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Arithmetic Calculator");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }

        });
    }

    class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

        private Image img;

        public ImagePanel(String img) {

            this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());

        }

        public ImagePanel(Image img) {

            this.img = img;

            Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);

        }
    }

    public static class SimpleArithmeticCalculator extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        private static final int BTN_ONE = 0;

        private static final int BTN_TWO = 1;

        private static final int BTN_THREE = 2;

        private static final int BTN_DIV = 3;

        private static final int BTN_FOUR = 4;

        private static final int BTN_FIVE = 5;

        private static final int BTN_SIX = 6;

        private static final int BTN_MULT = 7;

        private static final int BTN_SEVEN = 8;

        private static final int BTN_EIGHT = 9;

        private static final int BTN_NINE = 10;

        private static final int BTN_MINUS = 11;

        private static final int BTN_ZERO = 12;

        private static final int BTN_DECIMAL = 13;

        private static final int BTN_POWER = 14;

        private static final int BTN_PLUS = 15;

        private static final int BTN_CLEAR = 16;

        private static final int BTN_PERCENT = 17;

        private static final int BTN_BACKSPACE = 18;

        private static final int BTN_CALC = 19;

        private static final int NUM_BUTTONS = 20;

        private static final int OP_MULT = 0;

        private static final int OP_DIV = 1;

        private static final int OP_PLUS = 2;

        private static final int OP_MINUS = 3;

        private static final int OP_POWER = 4;

        private static final int OP_PERCENT = 5;

        private static char[] buttonTexts = {'7', '8', '9', '/', '4',
            '5', '6', '*', '1', '2',
            '3', '-', '0', '.', '^',
            '+', 'C', '%', '<', '='};

        private static final int[] buttonKeys = {
            KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD7, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD8, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD9, KeyEvent.VK_DIVIDE, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD4,
            KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD5, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD6, KeyEvent.VK_MULTIPLY, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD1, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2,
            KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD3, KeyEvent.VK_MINUS, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0, KeyEvent.VK_STOP, '^',
            KeyEvent.VK_PLUS, KeyEvent.VK_C, '%', KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE, KeyEvent.VK_ENTER
        };

        private Font font;

        private JButton[] buttons;

        private JTextField displayText;

        public JPanel calcPanel;

        private JPanel textPanel;

        private JPanel buttonPanel;

        private String buffer;

        private int op;

        private int opStored;

        private double lhs;

        private double rhs;

        private double rhsStored;

        private boolean left;

        private boolean clear;

        private char lastAction;

        public SimpleArithmeticCalculator() {

            super();

            buffer = new String("0.0");

            op = -1;

            opStored = -1;

            lhs = 0.0;

            rhs = 0.0;

            rhsStored = 0.0;

            left = true;

            clear = true;

            lastAction = '=';

            font = Font.decode("Courier PLAIN 24");

            try {

                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            calcPanel = new JPanel();
            calcPanel.setOpaque(false);

            textPanel = new JPanel();
            textPanel.setOpaque(false);

            buttonPanel = new JPanel();
            buttonPanel.setOpaque(false);

            textPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0, 0));

            buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 10, 10, 10));

            displayText = new JTextField("", 20);

            displayText.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);

            displayText.setFont(font);

            displayText.setEditable(false);

            textPanel.add(displayText);

            buttons = new JButton[NUM_BUTTONS];

            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BUTTONS; ++i) {

                buttons[i] = new JButton("" + buttonTexts[i]);

                buttons[i].setMnemonic(buttonKeys[i]);

                buttons[i].setFont(font);

                buttons[i].setMinimumSize(new Dimension(50, 50));

                buttons[i].setActionCommand("" + buttonTexts[i]);

                buttons[i].addActionListener(this);

                buttonPanel.add(buttons[i]);

            }

            buttons[BTN_POWER].setText("^");

            buttons[BTN_PERCENT].setText("%");

            buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

            textPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

            calcPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            calcPanel.add(textPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            calcPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            add(calcPanel);

            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BUTTONS; ++i) {

                buttons[i].setMaximumSize(buttons[i].getSize());

            }

        }

        public void SetColors(Color bg, Color textbg, Color textcolor) {

            calcPanel.setBackground(bg);

            calcPanel.setVisible(true);

            calcPanel.setOpaque(false);

            buttonPanel.setBackground(bg);

            buttonPanel.setVisible(true);

            buttonPanel.setOpaque(false);

            textPanel.setBackground(bg);

            textPanel.setOpaque(false);

            textPanel.setVisible(true);

            displayText.setBackground(textbg);

            displayText.setForeground(textcolor);

            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BUTTONS; ++i) {

                buttons[i].setForeground(textcolor);

            }

        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {

            String action = ev.getActionCommand();

            char c = action.charAt(0);

            boolean calc = false;

            if (c == buttonTexts[BTN_CLEAR]) {

                buffer = "";

                left = true;

            } else if (c == buttonTexts[BTN_BACKSPACE]) {

                if (buffer.length() > 0) {

                    buffer = buffer.substring(0, buffer.length() - 1);

                }

                if (lastAction == buttonTexts[BTN_CALC]) {

                    left = true;

                }

                clear = false;

            } else if ((c == buttonTexts[BTN_CALC]) || isOpCharacter(c)) {

                int opCurrent = op;

                if (c == buttonTexts[BTN_CALC]) {

                    if (!left) {

                        calc = true;

                        if (isOpCharacter(lastAction)) {

                            rhs = GetBufferValue();

                            rhsStored = rhs;

                            opCurrent = op;

                            opStored = op;

                        } else if (lastAction == buttonTexts[BTN_CALC]) {

                            rhs = rhsStored;

                            opCurrent = opStored;

                        } else {

                            rhs = GetBufferValue();

                            rhsStored = rhs;

                            opCurrent = op;

                            opStored = op;

                        }

                    }

                } else if (isOpCharacter(c)) {

                    opStored = op;

                    if (c == buttonTexts[BTN_MULT]) {
                        op = OP_MULT;
                    }

                    if (c == buttonTexts[BTN_DIV]) {
                        op = OP_DIV;
                    }

                    if (c == buttonTexts[BTN_PLUS]) {
                        op = OP_PLUS;
                    }

                    if (c == buttonTexts[BTN_MINUS]) {
                        op = OP_MINUS;
                    }

                    if (c == buttonTexts[BTN_POWER]) {
                        op = OP_POWER;
                    }

                    if (c == buttonTexts[BTN_PERCENT]) {
                        op = OP_PERCENT;
                    }

                    if (lastAction == buttonTexts[BTN_CALC]) {

                        lhs = GetBufferValue();

                        clear = true;

                    } else if (isOpCharacter(lastAction)) {

                    } else {

                        if (left) {

                            lhs = GetBufferValue();

                            left = false;

                        } else {

                            calc = true;

                            rhs = GetBufferValue();

                            opCurrent = opStored;

                            opStored = op;

                        }

                        clear = true;

                    }

                }

                if (calc) {

                    double result = 0.0;

                    if (opCurrent == OP_MULT) {
                        result = lhs * rhs;
                    }

                    if (opCurrent == OP_DIV) {
                        result = lhs / rhs;
                    }

                    if (opCurrent == OP_PLUS) {
                        result = lhs + rhs;
                    }

                    if (opCurrent == OP_MINUS) {
                        result = lhs - rhs;
                    }

                    if (opCurrent == OP_POWER) {
                        result = Math.pow(lhs, rhs);
                    }

                    if (opCurrent == OP_PERCENT) {
                        result = lhs / 100;
                    }

                    lhs = result;

                    buffer = "" + result;

                    clear = true;

                }

            } else {

                if (lastAction == buttonTexts[BTN_CALC]) {

                    left = true;

                }

                if (clear) {

                    buffer = "";

                    clear = false;

                }

                if (c == buttonTexts[BTN_DECIMAL]) {

                    if (buffer.indexOf('.') == -1) {

                        if (buffer.length() == 0 || (buffer.length() == 1 && buffer.charAt(0) == '-')) {

                            buffer += "0";

                        }

                        buffer += ".";

                    }

                } else if (c == buttonTexts[BTN_ZERO]) {

                    if (buffer.length() == 0 || (buffer.length() == 1 && buffer.charAt(0) == '-')) {

                        buffer += "0.";

                    } else if (buffer.length() > 0 && (isNonZeroNumber(buffer.charAt(0))
                            || (buffer.charAt(0) == '-' && isNonZeroNumber(buffer.charAt(1))))) {

                        buffer += "0";

                    } else if (buffer.compareTo("0") == 0 || buffer.compareTo("-0") == 0) {

                    } else {

                        buffer += "0";

                    }

                } else {

                    if (!buffer.equals("0") && !buffer.equals("-0")) {

                        buffer += c;

                    }

                }

            }

            lastAction = c;

            displayText.setText(buffer);

        }

        public double GetBufferValue() {

            double d = 0.0;

            try {

                d = Double.parseDouble(buffer);

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

                System.out.println("NumberFormatException in GetBufferValue()");

            }

            return d;

        }

        public boolean isOpCharacter(char c) {

            return ((c == buttonTexts[BTN_MULT])
                    || (c == buttonTexts[BTN_DIV])
                    || (c == buttonTexts[BTN_PLUS])
                    || (c == buttonTexts[BTN_MINUS])
                    || (c == buttonTexts[BTN_POWER])
                    || (c == buttonTexts[BTN_PERCENT]));

        }

        public boolean isNumericCharacter(char c) {

            return ((c == buttonTexts[BTN_ZERO])
                    || (c == buttonTexts[BTN_ONE])
                    || (c == buttonTexts[BTN_TWO])
                    || (c == buttonTexts[BTN_THREE])
                    || (c == buttonTexts[BTN_FOUR])
                    || (c == buttonTexts[BTN_FIVE])
                    || (c == buttonTexts[BTN_SIX])
                    || (c == buttonTexts[BTN_SEVEN])
                    || (c == buttonTexts[BTN_EIGHT])
                    || (c == buttonTexts[BTN_NINE])
                    || (c == buttonTexts[BTN_DECIMAL]));

        }

        public boolean isNonZeroNumber(char c) {

            return (c == buttonTexts[BTN_ONE]
                    || c == buttonTexts[BTN_TWO]
                    || c == buttonTexts[BTN_THREE]
                    || c == buttonTexts[BTN_FOUR]
                    || c == buttonTexts[BTN_FIVE]
                    || c == buttonTexts[BTN_SIX]
                    || c == buttonTexts[BTN_SEVEN]
                    || c == buttonTexts[BTN_EIGHT]
                    || c == buttonTexts[BTN_NINE]);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The window is very small and the background doesn't show up w/ this code, but I will edit it. Thank you for calmly trying to help me. I appreciate it.

Comment: Going to need two things, the background image and the `SimpleArithmeticCalculator` source to test it further...

Comment: I misread. It didn't show up after I typed the url for the image in I meant to say. I know you didn't include the url in there, but even after I added it, it didn't show up I meant to say.

Comment: I just noticed that you `ImagePanel` was using a `null` layout, this an incredibly bad thing to be doing.  You should make use of an appropriate layout manager to manage your components.

Comment: Unless you can provide me with `SimpleArithmeticCalculator` and a link to the background image, it will be very difficult to help you further

Comment: I am pressed for time and can't do that SSCEE thing or whatever it's called, but I'll add the code to the question. The background image is: http://i926.photobucket.com/albums/ad110/Khamani_Moore/01_Crane_AGweb_zpsfee613ca.jpg

Comment: +1, but I would have been more impressed if you used a JLabel for the background to show the OP how the ImagePanel could be replaced by two lines of code (like I suggested in the prvious posting) :)

Comment: Okay, I love the subliminal insults @camickr but the thing is... I just fixed it on my own. See the TestCalculator class that I just added to my question because I don't know how to add it here yet. Notice the astericks because I couldn't bold the code. ^^ I did it null layout and all. :) :) :) So, what were you saying about a JLabel??? Okay. Thanks! Actually, on the last post you wrote on about when my buttons wouldn't show up, camickr, the other answerer fully helped me, but I still listened to you. Just letting you know you didn't achieve all that you're trying to rub it in that you did. :)

Comment: @camickr In my examples, absolutely (should have used a `JLabel`), but the OP is actually resizing the image within the `paintComponent` method

Comment: The order in which you are doing things is messing up the ability for anything to really make accurate calculations about the preferred size of anything. Check the updates...

Comment: `the OP is actually resizing the image within the paintComponent method` - which leads to more confusing code because the OP is basing the preferred/minimum/maximum sizes on the size of the image. So if the frame ever was resized all the hardcoded calculations would be out of sync. @user3078712, `I did it null layout and all` - I'm not saying it can't be done with a null layout. I'm saying the code is more confusing, longer to write and harder to maintain because you are effectively writing your layout manager. One of the rules of programming is to not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I just said that I fixed it, so why were you all trying to still suggest things an two comments ago? That's like when you asked why I posted this question after you imagined I asked it before, lol. Anyways, if I'm the one making the code, then why does it matter how confusing it is for anyone else after I make it work how I want it to? To a certain degree, if it works, then it must make sense enough to compile. :) I understand if it's confusing and you're trying to help me, but it's fine. My professor is just checking to see if it works. @MadProgrammer I see nothing funny? Where's the joke?

Comment: @user3078712 I was laughing at myself not you ;) Sorry did realise you'd come to solution.  Code you make today will need to be changed tomorrow, best to make the best effort to make it less confusing (for yourself). It's also good practice and habit to always try and right clean code.  What you do when you think no one is watching is more important then what you do when they are ;)

Comment: I'm not planning on working with Java after this semester. It's too stressful. I was minoring in it, but not I'm just trying to make everything work, that's all. Thanks for helping, though.

Comment: Best of luck then - You're really close to a solution ;)

Comment: +1 for calling setResizable(boolean) BEFORE calling pack()

Answer (score 2):

> I only posted three questions on this site, and none specifically about frame.setResizable(false); before this one!

I know this is your first question about the setResizable() method. I am saying the setResizable() method is not working the way you expect because your code is all messed up because you have not listened to the advice you have been given in the past. If you had listened to the advice then using the setResizable(false) would not have been a problem.

```
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);           
frame.getContentPane().add(calc);
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(358,379));
frame.pack();
...
panel.add(calc);
```

You add the "panel" and "calc" to the content pane. You where specifically told the default layout of a JFrame is a BorderLayout and you can't add two panels to the CENTER (which is the default when you don't specify a constraint)

You then pack() the frame and add "calc" to "panel". This is changing the structure of components in the frame. Again you where told that you must add all components to the frame BEFORE doing the pack().

You were then given advice on how to use a panel with an image as a background and how to add that "background panel to the frame and add the "calculated panel" to the background. All of this code is extremely simple when you use the appropriate layout managers as was shown to you.

Your code now is so messed up because you are hardcoding the preferred, minimum and maximum sizes everywhere. Your sizes may take into account the size of the image, but they don't take into account the size of the title bar and borders around the frame, so the setResizable( false ) method is not working as you expect.

If instead you would use layout managers as was demonstrated in your other posting there would be no need for you to hard code sizes anywhere in you class and you code would work exactly the same whether you used setRisizable(false) or not.

Also, yesterday I told you that the follow statements are not needed:

```
panel.setVisible(true);
calc.setVisible(true);
```

because they are already visible by default. Yet you still included these statement. Now this will not cause a problem, but it just goes to show how little you listened to my advice.

Comment: `ImagePanel` is using a `null` layout, the OP eventually adds the `calc` to the `ImagePane`, so I assume they've use `setSize` within `SimpleArithmeticCalculator`...which is all compounding the underlying problems...

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my point, the hardcoding of sizes everywhere is causing problems. I gave the OP suggestions yesterday on how to use a layout manager with the background panel so that the calculator could be added to it.

Comment: Just making sure you saw it to ;)